# Get distinct element from a List<MyList> in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, duplicates, items, maplist

Hi and thanks for the support if anyone answers:

I have a List that I get from an mysql query and it returns several elements in my list. I receive something like this in Flutter:

```
[0]:ListaTotPaises
gravedad:"3"
pais:"Colombia"
total:"1"

[1]:ListaTotPaises
gravedad:"2"
pais:"Colombia"
total:"1"

[2]:ListaTotPaises
gravedad:"2"
pais:"Spain"
total:"2"
```

I want to get de different "pais" from this List. In this case I want to work with the values "Colombia" and "Spain" and not twice Colombia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` to get all `pais` then call `toSet` to remove duplicates and finally call `toList`.

```dart
myList.map((e) => e.pais).toSet().toList();
```

You could also use `map` + `contains` + `forEach` method to solve this:

```dart
final allPais = myList.map((e) => e.pais);
final distinctPais = [];
allPais.forEach((e) {
  if (!distinctPais.contains(e)) {
    distinctPais.add(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution using `retainWhere`

```
final sets = Set(); 
myList.retainWhere((e) => sets.add(e.pais));
```